# Listing Users via Azure DevOps Server 2020 (On-prem) REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2020

The standard answer online seem to be to use [Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0). Has this been removed? My response regardless of query complexity, from basic list to with specific ID, returns 404.
Can it really be that there is no supported endpoint of getting users via the REST Api?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Users-List` to get a list of all users in a given scope.

For the REST API to list Users in Azure DevOps, you can follow the below syntax:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

It will return the users with specific detailed information.

Comment: Hi, this does not work. It yields a 404 on Azure Devops Server 2020.
I also tried a few different variations of this, for example searching for a specific using given the subject identifier, none work.